# Power Query error - DataFormat.Error: We couldn't parse the input provided as a Date value. Details: 18.07.2023

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have am error when I try to change type in DATE.
ON the firs I get error the second is ok.

I want to modify from GEneral Type in Date!
The cels has the same format of date DD.MM.YYYY and I want the format MM/DD/YYYY.
Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you can add a custom column or transform it like

```
= Date.FromText([YourColumnNameHere], [Format="dd.MM.yyyy"])
```

and that should return the date in your local format

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so, please toggle checkmark to mark question as solved